# Play Framework return a json from Controller

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to return a primitive JSON array from my Playframework controller in java.

what would be a smart way? ...

Sorry for asking here, but playframework doku is offline...

Comment: Just try `return ok(myJson)`, where myJson is your json as a Jackson ArrayNode (as far as I remember, play uses Jackson to handle JSON in Java)

Comment: Or you can write `cache:https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJsonActions` in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minimal example that wokres fine:

```
 ObjectNode allProcesses = Json.newObject();

    allProcesses.put("Prozess1", "Hallo ich bin ein Prozess");


    return ok(allProcesses);
```

Comment: Wow, I just found out that the documentaion is always available at `http://localhost:9000/@documentation` if a play server is started in dev mode.